# Классы против структур

Tags: структуры, code-style, c++

Стоит ли в своих кодах C++ использовать структуры? Я так понимаю структуры это пережитки языка С. С одной стороны структуры в написании и использования проще классов но они подрывают принципы ООП.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4a1hcx0y.aspx Все что нужно знать о структурах и классах можно прочитать в официальной документации...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В `Си++` основная разница между структурой и классом - это модификатор доступа, который используется по умолчанию для их членов. Для классов, по умолчанию используется модификатор `private`, а для структур - `public`. Конечно, **принципы инкапсуляции структуры таким образом подрывают**, но классы, в свою очередь **тормозят стадию проектирования**, которая затрагивает структурную эволюцию проекта.

Т.е., к примеру: выделить класс из структуры проще, чем из класса, т.к. для класса придется пересматривать логику взаимодействия свойств, которые ранее были на одном уровне доступа. Этот процеесс выливается в дописывание/переписывание методов, обеспечивающих инкапсуляцию.

Все было бы хорошо, если бы на какой-то очередной стадии проектирования Вы вдруг не осознаете, что порой ходите кругами, делая пустую работу, прикрывая тылы инкапсуляции.

С одной стороны, можно конечно занять позицию рецензора `Си++` и следовать "букве закона ООП", т.е. смириться с этой неизбежной бюрократией. Но с другой стороны - это ведь Ваш проект, и Вы вправе строить его по своим законам, давая волю свободному проектированию какого-то сложного класса на структурах, а его финальные версии закрепить на классах по всем правилам `ООП`.

Comment: Ещё вроде отличаются тем, что структура значимый тип данных, а класс ссылочный или я с С# путаю?

Comment: Это уже определения из области `Си#`, там, насколько я понял (не пользуюсь Си#), структуры с **приватным** модификатором доступа по умолчанию, а не с публичным. Насчет ссылочного типа - аналогично, для `Си++` это неверно.

Answer (score 5):

> Стоит ли в своих кодах C++ использовать структуры?

По мере надобности да.

> Я так понимаю структуры это пережитки языка С.

нет.

> С одной стороны структуры в написании и использования проще классов

и чем же они проще? `struct` длиннее `class`:) вот код для медитации:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct test {
  test() {
  // у структур есть конструктор
     q = 1;
     cout << "ctor" << endl;
  }

  ~test() {
     // и деструктор!
     cout << "dtor" << endl;
  }
  int get_q() {return q;}
private:
  // и даже приватная часть
  int q;
};

class mega:public test {
   // и от них можно наследоваться.

};

int main() {
   test t;
   cout << t.get_q() << endl;
   mega m;
   return 0;
}
```

> но они подрывают принципы ООП.

нет. Просто по умолчанию в классах все приватное, а в  структурах - публичное. Но это просто соглашение. Есть ещё пару мелочей.

Comment: все таки непонятно. изначально в С структуры не было заложено использования методов, конструкторов и деструкторов. А раз в С++ все это ввели и структура стала такая же как класс то зачем вообще использовать структуры.

Comment: Не знаю точно, как по новому стандарту, но раньше для структур гарантировалось POD. А это тает возможность загружать одним махом заголовки файлов и тому подобное. Для классов POD вроде не гарантировался.

Для классов создаются конструкторы по умолчанию. Для структур - нет.

Comment: что такое POD?

Comment: Википедия [POD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)? - нет, не пользуемся:)

За одно узнаете разницу между структурами и классами.

Comment: единтсвенная мелочь в том что если структура тривильна и является POD, то она совместима по образу в памяти с такой же структурой, использованной кодом на языке Си. Тем не менее даже класс может быть тривиальным и POD, но совсестимости не гарантируется и правило псевдонимов соблюдается жестче

Answer (score 5):

При правильном использовании структуры не нарушают принципов ООП. Применять их следует для логического объединения данных, когда нет смысла, да и логического основания для создания объектов. 
Например у нас есть картинка. Для сохраниения данных о ее размерах нам нет смысла создавать класс. В этом случае гораздо лучше и удобнее использовать структуру, которая, являясь членом класса "картинка", объединит в себе поля "высота" и "ширина". Чаще всего эти данные будут требоваться нам вместе, поэтому и получать их у картинки будет логичнее вместе.

Comment: - [`Mutable structs are evil.`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) Это же утверждение для `C#` в должной мере относится и к `non-legacy C++,` соответственно, имеет смысл стремиться при написании кода к `immutab'ельности` типов данных.

- Конкретно в вашем примере, ничто не мешает пользователю после создания объекта с размерами картинки вручную изменить его значение ширины, что, в свою очередь приведет к рассинхронизации данных. Особенно, если код пишет не `Const Nazi` разработчик.

Comment: Я говорил не о постоянном хранении этих данных, а о временном. Пример: для отрисовки мне необходимо знать ее размеры, тогда гораздо удобнее получить их структурой (констаннтной ссылкой на нее), чем получать двумя отдельными элементами.
Опять же, здесь обсуждается сама концепция структур, а не их конкретноу применение. Хотя соглашусь, пример не идеален.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, вот меня в подобных постоянных рассуждениях об опасностях, исходящих от толпы неграмотных "программистов", просто ставящих перед собой цель изувечить наш замечательный проект, всегда удивляет игнорирование обсуждения таких лежащих на поверхности фатальных действий, как например, деление на ноль.

Мне кажется, что реальная проблема в другом. А именно, в слишком больших программах.

Comment: @avp: а что делать, если задание сложное, и сложность и вправду зашкаливает? Не дело программиста определять сложность проекта, он человек подневольный.

Comment: @VladD, не совсем понял, в чем вопрос:

    а что делать, если задание сложное ...

???

Наверное, поступить честно. Сказать, что не могу его сделать и найти другое задание (другую работу).

--

А подневольные - это вояки (и ЗК).

Comment: @avp: Мне на самом деле нравятся сложные задания. Для них приходится делать больше предосторожностей, кое-что будет не так эффективно, как код на чистом C, но сдаваться как-то неохота. (Эх, когда же наконец сделают чат?) Я осознаю, что в доведении до совершенства кода маленькой концептуально чистой утилиты (Unix-way) есть своя прелесть, а в преодолении мегасложности огромного проекта — своя. И я бы не отказался ни от того, ни от другого. Чем больше сложность, тем чаще приходится жертвовать эффективностью ради концептуальности. Но без таких жертв "Фотошоп" никогда не был бы написан.

Comment: @VladD, IMHO  на сегодняшнем железе именно стремление к эффективности заставляет всех делать большими командами мегасложные монолитные программы.

Но, по большому счету, это путь в никуда. Я не верю, что можно придумать простой язык, который позволит массово делать хорошие монолитные системы. А сложный язык большинство программистов не в состоянии освоить и будут писать программы с ошибками.

Возможно, что и с большими системами из маленьких взаимодействующих программ, будет та же история (просто сложность сместится в другую область). Но этот путь мы еще толком не пробовали.

Comment: >а что делать, если задание сложное

 --  
>Наверное, поступить честно. Сказать, что не могу его сделать и найти другое задание (другую работу).

Наверное, здесь стоит разделить сложную задачу на несколько более простых. Предложить способ их взаимодействия. Отказываться от сложных задач - тоже не дело. Инженер - тоже организатор и должен уметь планировать свою работу даже в таких условиях. Просто отказаться может позволить себе только узкоспециализированный или временный, незаинтересованный работник, например - на аутсорсинге.

>А подневольные - это вояки (и ЗК).

угу